# Increase code coverage

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, code

folks, I have a scheduled class from which I am calling my future method but I am not able to increase test coverage for certain section please help me with it.

Scheduled class (100 % covered)

```
global class ActivateCFSUsers Implements Schedulable {

    public Interface IScheduleDispached {
        void execute(SchedulableContext sc);
    }
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {

        Type targetType = Type.forName('HANDLERNAME');
        if(targetType != null){
            IScheduleDispached obj =(IScheduleDispached)targetType.newInstance();
            obj.execute(sc);
        }
    }
}
```

HANDLER CLASS That is being called (75% covered)

```
public class HANDLERNAME implements ActivateCFSUsers.IScheduleDispached {

     public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {

        List<User> newusers = [Select Id,CFS_Activation_Date__c from user where (Profile.Name='CTCT Solution Provider (Login Based)'OR Profile.Name='CTCT Solution Provider (Named)')AND lmscons__Cornerstone_ID__c=NULL AND lmscons__CFS_Status__c='Not CFS user']; 

        Set<Id> sendset = new Set<Id>();
        for(integer i=0;i<newusers.size();++i)
            // Next line is not covered
            sendset.add(newusers[i].Id);  
        if(newusers.size()>0)
            System.debug(newusers.size()+' new users found will give them license in a sometime');
        if(newusers.size()>0)
            //Next line which is call to my future method is not covered
            UserHandler.enrollCFSUser(sendset);
    } 

}
```

Test Class (I am not testing anything as of now my first objective is to increase coverage)

```
@isTest
private class testsActivateCFSUsers {
@isTest
private static void test() {
Test.StartTest();
ActivateCFSUsers sh1 = new ActivateCFSUsers();
String sch = '0 0 23 * * ?'; 
system.schedule('Test Territory Check', sch, sh1); 
Test.stopTest(); 
}   
}
```

Comment: post your test class

Comment: @RohitMourya Updated

Comment: @RohitMourya I cannot see your answer Code coverage increased to 100% thanks man

Comment: Now you can see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not creating test data properly. You're querying `User` but haven't created any `user` in your test class. Because of this, your query results 0 records. It's a standard practice to create test data for your controller. Refer below code in which I've created a user with profile which you're referring in your query. Though below code is not tested but it will give some idea:

```
@isTest
private class testsActivateCFSUsers {
    @isTest
    private static void test() {
        Profile p = [select id,Name from profile where name = 'CTCT Solution Provider (Login Based)'];

        User TestUser = new User(alias = 'standt', email = 'standardusersdf23423@testorg.com', MobilePhone = '9827261629',
                                 emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8', lastname = 'Testing', languagelocalekey = 'en_US',
                                 localesidkey = 'en_US', profileid = p.Id, Mobile_number__c = '9827261629',
                                 timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles', username = 'test1User123sdf234234@test.com');
        insert TestUser;

        Test.StartTest();
        ActivateCFSUsers sh1 = new ActivateCFSUsers();
        String sch = '0 0 23 * * ?'; 
        system.schedule('Test Territory Check', sch, sh1); 
        Test.stopTest(); 
    }   
}
```

Comment: You don't have to create users in test classes. Users data is pre-available in test classes. For details check this [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm).

Comment: @Mahmood if that's the case then code coverage should have been 100%

Comment: @Mahmood I think this in not the best practice to use actual data in the test class.

Comment: Users are visible in test methods. Maybe none of them matched the criteria though.